# Is it possible to get the folders back after using rm command in git bash?

Tags: git

Some of my folders on local repository were deleted but the changes were not committed to master branch can those folders be fetched again ?

Comment: If you never committed those folders into git, and removed them on disk, then only the file system can help you, like either a file system undo/restore feature/program or a backup. If you have none of that, and didn't commit into git, then no, those are gone.

Comment: You can try to undo from the IDE that you use if you had it opened while deleting. Which helped me get back files several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they were committed somewhere, you can use `git checkout <commit-id> <directory>`.

If they were committed, but not pushed, and the commits were orphaned, so they're now on no branches, they'll still be on the reflog, and you can still use the checkout command. Use `git reflog`, `git reflog --name-status` and `git show <commit-id>` to find the commit ID if required.

If they were not committed, but were stashed (with `git stash -u` if they were new files), use `git stash list --name-status`, `git stash show stash@{<number>}` and `git checkout stash@{<number>} <directory>` to locate and bring them back.

If they were stashed but the stash was dropped/popped, you can use `git fsck --no-reflog` and `git show <id>` to locate them in a list of orphaned objects until they get garbage collected by git when they reach a configured age [(full easier instructions)](https://gist.github.com/joseluisq/7f0f1402f05c45bac10814a9e38f81bf).

If you never committed or stashed them, and you have no other kind of backup, then they are gone. I can only suggest to learn committing or stashing regularly.